# Do 'orientation' and 'display' properties of manifest.json only work when service worker is registered?

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps, manifest.json

I'm building my first progressive web app.  I haven't got as far as registering a service worker just yet, but I have created a manifest.json file, which looks like this:

```
{
  "short_name": "My PWA",
  "name": "My Progressive Web Application",
  "start_url": "/",
  "background_color": "#222",
  "display": "standalone",
  "scope": "/",
  "theme_color": "#222",
  "orientation": "portrait",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "/assets/images/logo-square-192.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "192x192"
    },
    {
      "src": "/assets/images/logo-square-512.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "512x512"
    }
  ]
}
```

I've loaded this onto a test server (not running over HTTPS currently, so I'm aware that a service worker won't work, hence I haven't got that far yet) and have looked at the site on Chrome latest on a new Nokia 6.1 running Android.  I notice that the 'display' property doesn't seem to be doing what it should, and I can also turn the device to landscape and browse the site in that orientation.  So it seems that the manifest.json file isn't doing anything.

I can't find any documentation stating whether the manifest.json file only becomes 'active' when a service worker is installed and/or via HTTPS so I wondered if anyone here could shed any light on this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

So a bit of experimentation later...  It seems the manifest.json rules only become active once the site has been added to the home-screen.  (I don't have a service worker to facilitate this yet, but it can be done in the browser settings).  So on Chrome/Android at least the manifest settings don't need HTTPS enabled nor a service worker.